# Permission to user1/repo denied to user2, can't push to two accounts without changing settings each time

Tags: github, ssh, ssh-config, multiple-accounts

I've seen some similar questions (in fact have tried the solution to every single one I've seen) but none have solved this. Essentially, **I want to push to two different Github accounts without changing my config file every time.**

I am trying to push to two different Github accounts from the same system, both with SSH. I am using WSL through VSCode. `ssh -T` works for both of my RSA files, both Github accounts have the corresponding SSH keys and I can push to each just fine, when my `.ssh/config` file has specific settings for each.

My `.ssh/config` file looks like this:

```
# Personal Account
Host github.com-user1
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    
# Work Account
Host github.com-user2
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user2
```

As is, pushing to account `user1` works fine, but trying to push to account `user2` gives error:

```
ERROR: Permission to user2/repo.git denied to user1.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

HOWEVER, if I change the second stanza (`#Work Account`)'s first line to just `Host github.com`, I can suddenly push to account user2! I just... can't push to user1. I get the reverse of the above error, now `Permission to user1/repo.git denied to user2.`

**I have tried:**
Setting *both* as `Host github.com`, but this reverts me to my original problem (can push only as user1.)

It seems like it's just picking the first stanza in the `.ssh/config` file it sees (while prioritizing `Host github.com`), but I need it to be responsive to which account I'm pushing from.

`git config user.name` and `user.email` are set to the correct values for each repo. User2 uses local config & User1 uses the global config, but I don't think this is the problem since I've been able to push to both without adjusting this.

I've added `PreferredAuthentications publickey` and `IdentitiesOnly yes` to both stanzas, and some others I've seen in others' configurations of this file, but none have changed the error that gets output.

`Control Panel > Manage Windows Credentials` has no GitHub credentials associated with it (I checked, there weren't any, nothing has been altered/removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've set up that stanza in your `~/.ssh/config`, you then need to change each remote name to use either `github.com-user1` or `github.com-user2` as the host name in the SSH URL.  That's the only way to get this to work reliably, and you can change the existing remote (e.g. `origin`) URL by running `git remote set-url NEW-URL`.

Also note that you need the `IdentitiesOnly yes` option in each stanza as well.

This is documented in [the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#multiple-accounts-ssh).